# sql loader load into multiple tables from single CSV file

Tags: sql, csv, plsql, sql-loader, ctl

The contents of the CSV file is as shown:

```
LOAD DATE,30-Nov-15
STORE,MANAGER NAME,PHONE Number  
519900,STEVEN FRENCH,905-271-3644  
520300,IAN MCGAUGHEY,519-672-9986  
512400,,416-665-4657  
512900,RAKESH PRASAD,905-672-6301
```

I want to add `30-Nov-15` to a column of `table1` and

```
519900,STEVEN FRENCH,905-271-3644  
520300,IAN MCGAUGHEY,519-672-9986  
512400,,416-665-4657  
512900,RAKESH PRASAD,905-672-6301
```

to 3 columns of `table2` using a single CTL file. Please help.

Comment: Are there any other columns in your `table1` apart from the `load date`?

Comment: yes there are other columns too. They need to be filled with constant values.

Comment: SQL\*Loader does have syntax for inserting into multiple tables but it requires the rows to have some indicator to distinguish the rows. It is a utility for loading data in a format which has been designed for it. If you want to load some randomly structured CSV fie you need a programmatic solution. Either some external code to pre-process the file, or some PL/SQL or external table solution.